# Multi-Column, Multi-Row PIVOT

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, pivot, unpivot

Consider that I have a table which contains data in the following form:

```
Foo_FK  MonthCode_FK  Activity_FK  SumResultsX  SumResultsY
-----------------------------------------------------------
1       201312        0            10           2
1       201312        1            5            1
1       201401        0            15           3
1       201401        1            7            2
2       201312        0            9            3
2       201312        1            1            2
2       201401        0            6            2
2       201401        1            17           4
```

For my purposes, it is safe to assume that this table is an aggregation which would have been created by a `GROUP BY` on `Foo_FK, MonthCode_FK, Activity_FK` with `SUM( ResultsA ), SUM( ResultsB )` to obtain the data, making `Foo_FK, MonthCode_FK, Activity_FK` unique per record.

If for some reason I found it preferable to `PIVOT` this table in a stored procedure to ease the amount of screwing around with SSRS I'd have to do ( and undoubtedly later maintain ), wishing to get the following format for consumption via a matrix tablix thingy:

```
Foo_FK  1312_0_X  1312_0_Y  1312_1_X  1312_1_Y  1401_0_X  1401_0_Y  1401_1_X  1401_1_Y  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       10        2         5         1         15        3         7         2
2       9         3         1         2         6         2         17        4
```

How would I go about doing this in a not-mental way?  Please refer to this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e76c7/16) at proof I am likely trying to use a hammer to build a device that pushes in nails.  Don't worry about a dynamic version as I'm sure I can figure that out once I'm guided through the static solution for this test case.

Right now, I've tried to create a `Foo_FK, MonthCode_FK` set via the following, which I then attempt to `PIVOT` ( [see the Fiddle for the full mess](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e76c7/16) ):

```
SELECT  Foo_FK = ISNULL( a0.Foo_FK, a1.Foo_FK ),
        MonthCode_FK = ISNULL( a0.MonthCode_FK, a1.MonthCode_FK ),
        [0_X] = ISNULL( a0.SumResultX, 0 ),
        [0_Y] = ISNULL( a0.SumResultY, 0 ),
        [1_X] = ISNULL( a1.SumResultX, 0 ),
        [1_Y] = ISNULL( a1.SumResultY, 0 )
FROM (  SELECT  Foo_FK, MonthCode_FK, Activity_FK, 
                SumResultX, SumResultY
        FROM    dbo.t_FooActivityByMonth
        WHERE   Activity_FK = 0 ) a0
FULL OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT  Foo_FK, MonthCode_FK, Activity_FK, 
                SumResultX, SumResultY
        FROM    dbo.t_FooActivityByMonth
        WHERE   Activity_FK = 1 ) a1
    ON  a0.Foo_FK = a1.Foo_FK;
```

I have come across some [excellent advice on this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21257388/1382359), so I'm in the process of performing some form of `UNPIVOT` before I twist everything back out using `PIVOT` and `MAX`, but if there's a better way to do this, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you should be able to do this by applying unpivot to your `SumResultX` and `SumResultY` columns first, then pivoting the data:

```
;with cte as
(
  select Foo_FK, 
    col = cast(MonthCode_FK as varchar(6))+'_'
            +cast(activity_fk as varchar(1))+'_'+sumresult, 
    value
  from dbo.t_FooActivityByMonth
  cross apply
  (
    values 
      ('X', SumResultX),
      ('Y', SumResultY)
  ) c (sumresult, value)
) 
select Foo_FK, 
  [201312_0_X], [201312_0_Y], [201312_1_X], [201312_1_Y],
  [201401_0_X], [201401_0_Y], [201401_1_X], [201401_1_Y]
from cte
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in ([201312_0_X], [201312_0_Y], [201312_1_X], [201312_1_Y],
              [201401_0_X], [201401_0_Y], [201401_1_X], [201401_1_Y])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7356f/17)