# Pivot tables with related columns

Tags: t-sql, pivot

This seems to me to be a trivial task, but due to (probably) lack of understanding the pivoting mechanism, I am having trouble finding a solution to it.

I have the following table with sample data:

```
id      code    created_datetime    sourceID
------  ----    ------------------- --------
481792  DEF     2016-12-04 18:31:00 398464
481792  JKH     2016-12-04 18:31:00 398464
486429  ABC     2010-09-07 09:29:00 302304
486429  DEF     2009-02-05 03:04:00 320903
486429  GHI     2009-02-05 03:04:00 320903
```

What I would like to get as a result is a pivot on the 'code' column, an indication of whether or not this code exists for an Id. The column 'created_datetime' I am trying to convert with SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,created_datetime,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) into a count of days up till now - and finally the sourceID. I had something like this in mind for the result (I really hope this is formatted correctly):

```
id      ABC ABC_sou ABC_days_active DEF DEF_sou DEF_days_active GHI GHI_sou GHI_days_active JKH JKH_sou JKH_days_active
------  --- ------- --------------- --- ------- --------------- --- ------- --------------- --- ------- ---------------
481792  0                           1   398464  211                                         1   398464  211
486429  1   302304  2491            1   320903  3070            1   320903  3070
```

One line pr. id, that is.

What I have attempted so far, without quite getting there, is inspired by this link:[PIVOT on Multiple Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21245893/pivot-on-multiple-columns), and using the example here, i came up with this:

```
select id,
  [ABC], [ABC_source], [ABC_days_active],
  [DEF], [DEF_source], [DEF_days_active],
  [GHI], [GHI_source], [GHI_days_active],
  [JKH], [JKH]_source], [JKH_days_active]
from
(
  SELECT  id, 
                code,
                source,
                col, value
        FROM MyTable
  cross apply
  (
    values
      ([code], CASE code WHEN NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END),
      ([code]+'_source', [source]),
      ([code]+'_date', CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY,created_datetime,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS varchar (20)))
  ) c (col, value)
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in ([ABC], [ABC_source], [ABC_date], [DEF], [DEF_source], [DEF_date],
              [GHI], [GHI_source], [GHI_date], [JKH], [JKH_source], [JKH_date])
) piv;
```

That gave me the correct columns (column names), but I still have the same number of rows as I started with. (And besides, 0 will only show as NULL, but I can live with that.)

Can you give me a hint to get me there? It is probably something I have just not interpreted correctly...

Comment: Try to select `piv.*`. You selected the `_active` columns, while they are not part of the pivot. All columns from the `FROM`-clause that are not used in the `PIVOT`, will be used to group upon. Also, it seems to me that you are trying to pivot two columns from the source table. `PIVOT` only supports one column to pivot by an aggregate function.

Comment: Aha! That did it - THANKS Aquillo!! How can I mark your comment at answer and give you credit for it?

Comment: You can't, I have posted my comment as an answer. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to select `piv.*`. You selected the `_active` columns, while they are not part of the pivot. All columns from the `FROM`-clause that are not used in the `PIVOT`, will be used to group upon. Also, it seems to me that you are trying to pivot two columns from the source table. `PIVOT` only supports one column to pivot by an aggregate function.